# The partial order induced by a preorder, and the functions respecting this induced p.o.

Tags: terminology, order-theory

Let $X$ be a non-empty set and let $\preceq$ be a preorder on $X$.

1. Is there a standard name for the induced equivalence relation '$\equiv$' on $X$ that satisfies: for every $x, y \in X$, $x \equiv y$ iff $x \preceq y$ and $x \succeq y$? Is there a standard name for the collection of equivalence classes associated with '$\equiv$'?
2. Let $Y$ be a non-empty set. Is there a standard name for those functions $f:X\rightarrow Y$ that respect the induced equivalence relation described above, i.e. those functions satisfying: whenever $x, y \in X$ are such that $x \preceq y$ and $x \succeq y$, $f(x) = f(y)$?

Comment: I think what you mean in 2. is the functions whose kernel is the equivalence relation you defined in 1. (Of course this doesn't answer anything.)

Comment: @amrsa: I'm not sure *kernel* is an adequate terminology here: firstly because $f$ may not be a homomorphism (no structure is specified on $Y$), and secondly because it can happen for some function $f$ and for some $x, y \in X$ that $f(x) = f(y)$, but either $x \not\preceq y$ or $x \not\succeq y$ (or both).

Comment: I see. I didn't anticipate your second objection. About the first, if $Y$ has no structure, it's the same as being an anti-chain, and then it would only be a homomorphism if $x \preceq y$ implied $f(x)=f(y)$, so again, your objection makes sense.